# Redux Persist not working after page reload or refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux, redux-persist

I was using react-toolkit but then decided to use redux-persist in order to persist my user reducer (ie my user data, like the access token and info), but when i added the redux persist and followed an online guide. t wasn't working as intended. even after reloading the page, the data still gets wiped out, Please how do i fix this issue?

I am using

```
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
"react-redux": "^8.1.1",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
```

Am using next js, react js and typescript

My store.js

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore, Store } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE } from "next-redux-wrapper";
import {
  persistStore,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";

import authReducer from "./slices/authSlice";
import teamReducer from "./slices/teamSlice";
import testimonialReducer from "./slices/testimonialSlice";
import currencyReducer from "./slices/currencySlice";
import subscriptionReducer from "./slices/subscriptionSlice";
import exchangeReducer from "./slices/exchangeSlice";
import referralReducer from "./slices/referralSlice";
import notificationReducer from "./slices/notificationSlice";
import tradeReducer from "./slices/tradeSlice";
import userReducer from "./slices/userSlice";

import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"; // defaults to localStorage for web
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

const combineReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  team: teamReducer,
  testimonial: testimonialReducer,
  currency: currencyReducer,
  subscription: subscriptionReducer,
  exchange: exchangeReducer,
  user: userReducer,
  referral: referralReducer,
  notification: notificationReducer,
  trade: tradeReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  whitelist: ["user"],
};

const persistedUserReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, combineReducer);

const makeStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: persistedUserReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: {
          ignoredActions: [
            FLUSH,
            REHYDRATE,
            PAUSE,
            PERSIST,
            PURGE,
            REGISTER,
            HYDRATE,
          ],
        },
      }).concat(thunk),
  });

const store = makeStore();

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const wrapper = createWrapper<Store>(makeStore, { debug: true });
```

my root app component _app.js

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { persistor, wrapper } from "../redux/store";
import { AuthProvider } from "../context/AuthProvider";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { store, props } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(pageProps)
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Layout isAuthenticated={false}>
            <Component {...props.pageProps} />
           </Layout>
        </AuthProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

my userSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { User } from "../../types/user";

// Interface representing the state structure of the User slice
interface UserState {
  user: User; // Data representing the user's profile
  balance: string; // User's balance as a string (could be a number, but maintained as a string for precision)
  token: string; // user access token
  isLoading?: boolean; // A flag to indicate if user-related actions are in progress
}

// Initial state for the User slice
const initialState: UserState = {
  user: {}, // Initially, there is no user data, so an empty object is used
  balance: "", // Initial balance is set to ""
  token: "", // Initial token is set to ""
  isLoading: false, // Initially, there are no loading actions, so isLoading is set to false
};

// Create the User slice using createSlice from Redux Toolkit
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user", // Name of the slice, used as the prefix for action types
  initialState, // Initial state for the slice
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<User>) => {
      // Reducer to update the user data when the "setUser" action is dispatched
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    setBalance: (state, action) => {
      // Reducer to update the user's balance when the "setBalance" action is dispatched
      state.balance = action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {},
});

// Export actions from the User slice
export const { setUser, setBalance } = userSlice.actions;

// Export the reducer function for the User slice to use in the Redux store
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

And then this is how i set my user

```
const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>()

 dispatch(setUser({
          ...userData,
          access_token: data.access_token
        }))
```

Please can someone tell me what's wrong or what am doing wrong
Thanks

Comment: 1. Ensure that the whitelist configuration in your persistConfig includes "user", as you intend to persist only the user slice. Make sure that the name matches the slice you're trying to persist.

2. The setUser action updates the user state, including the access_token. Make sure that this action is not being dispatched again with an empty access_token after the initial setup. You might want to add a condition to avoid setting an empty access_token.

Comment: @SyedArifIqbal yes i have checked all that as you can see in the code, even before reloading i check my state in the devtools to make sure that the data is still inside it before reloading the page and after that it just gets wiped out

Comment: Are you trying to instantiate the store on the server side using Server-Side Rendering? Redux-Persist works on the client side.

Comment: @DrewReese no am only trying to use it on the client side not on the server side, cause i will still need to export it as a static site to my cpanel

Comment: Isn't there some `"use client"` directive you should specify in the `component _app.js` file so it's rendered client-side?